# Magento 2 import "please wait" error

Tags: magento2, import

I just new installed Magento 2.2.3. Import product CSV problem gave me a headache for 2 days. The import file only just test file contains 5 rows. I try to import on localhost is work properly. But on server is always stop on "Please Wait" screen. The Web server is Centos7. I already changed on /etc/php.ini

> max_execution_time=500, max_input_time=1200, max_input_vars = 3000, memory_limit=500M

Any configure I missed?

[import csv](http://www.comcomputer.com:8081/catalog_product.csv)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MacOs?

A common issue I got in the past which is I opened the export CSV file by using Excel on MacOs and I saved it.

The solution for this is In excel save as "Windows Comma Separated (.csv)"

Comment: I use open office. And the CSV can import in xampp localhost no problem, but cannot import on server. Not sure is the CSV file issue or server configure issue.

Comment: Can you upload your csv import file?

Comment: Thanks, @thanhdv2811, I have upload the csv file above. BTW,, I am using Windows 10.